# Use argparse module with argument for a function

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to execute my function `play()`

```
import argparse
from num2words import num2words

def play():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--b", default=100,type=int,help="b")
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    for file in reversed(range(file)):
        print(num2words(iteration) + " there are")
        print(num2words(iteration) + " there are")
```

I keep running in python commandline:

```
>>> import myfile
>>> file.play()
```

but it keeps using the `default=100`, how can i specify the argument `--b 10` for example?

Comment: looks like you're calling from the interactive interpreter (REPL), not the shell (command line)

Comment: How can i from shell ?

Comment: You can overwrite `sys.argv` value and argparse will take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your program to:

```
import argparse
from num2words import num2words

def play():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--b", default=100,type=int,help="b")
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    for file in reversed(range(file)):
        print(num2words(iteration) + " there are")
        print(num2words(iteration) + " there are")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

and add all the missing code not shown in your question.

On the command line:

```
python my_file_name.py --b 10
```

The command line is not the interactive Python interpreter, i.e. the `>>>` prompt. Type `exit()` and then enter this line. The command line is the on Linux/Mac OS X for example the `bash` shell; on Windows the "DOS box".

For interactive work try:

```
 >>> import sys
 >>> sys.argv.extend(['--b', '10'])
 >>> import myfile
 >>> file.play()
```

Comment: what is file?  what is iteration?

Comment: If I do this in command line I get:     python file.py --b 10
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Whatever the OP has in the program but is not shown in code of the question.

Comment: Its not relevant for the question

Comment: If I call: if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.call(['./file.py', 10]) it gives me an error of: "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and got a bit farther, but still getting this error, when i follow these steps: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - thoughts?? I ran: sys.argv.extend(['--b', 10]) (Note, no quotes around 10)

Comment: This is an error when you use the `10`. Likely, this has nothing to do with `argparse`. Create another question with the relevant code and the full traceback. Hint: The traceback will show line numbers. Make sure to include the code around these lines of your module.